# Run a specific test case, downloading all mvn dependencies

Tags: java, maven, testing

I need to run a single test case on a java project, but without using mvn or gradle. I downloaded through an mvn command all the dependencies of the project, how can I do at this point to invoke the single method, making him use the dependencies he needs?

Comment: `mvn test -Dtest=MyTestClass#myTestMethod`. Don't try and do it manually - why would you want to?

Comment: I can't use mvn to launch my test cases. I should do it simply by invoking java

Comment: Why can't you? You seem to be able to run Maven on the same machine to download dependencies. Running a test framework like JUnit by hand is far from trivial.

Comment: I'd have to do it for execution time issues. mvn takes too many seconds to run a single test case (even 7-8 seconds).

Comment: @broke31 If you build your artifact I bet the tests have already been executed. Usually you do `mvn clean package` the unit tests have already been done...Furthermore I don't understand what you've mentioned `single test case takes 7-8 seconds) ...please show the log output and what is your test doing ? Which version of Maven/JDK etc. you are using?

Comment: I run mvn install -DskipTests , then I run the command of mvn -Dtest=className#methodName test inside a for loop, because I have to run the same test n times, each rerun mvn takes about 8 seconds to finish. 
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_242, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

Comment: Put the for loop in the test. Why would you want to run the same test N times - a test should pass or fail once.

Comment: Because some types of tests are not deterministic, and I'm studying after how many times a change happens

Comment: What about running the loop as @BoristheSpider said and log out which runs of the loop succeeded and which failed?

Comment: The question is what kind of unit test framework you are using? JUnit 4 there exist some example code to handle that. In [JUnit Jupiter](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-repeated-tests) it's very easy. Furthermore if you have a test which is not deterministic you should check the code of your test as well as the code which should be tested...

Comment: BTW: `mvn install` is usually not necessary only `mvn verify` or in your case `mvn test` is sufficient.

Comment: These are not my projects using Junit4. My goal is to verify whether or not those test cases are deterministic.

Comment: Running a test N times and it returning the same result no more proves determinism than flipping a coin N times. Assuming you have knowledge of the distribution of the probability of the supposed non-determinism you could run statistical tests and prove to a certain confidence interval - but that’s probably not going to be the guarantee you want.

Comment: Currently, the technique to detect flaky behavior (see flaky test) is to do a rerun N times of a test case and check if there has been a change in the result. I have to check whether or not the downloaded projects have flaky behavior.